# What's the best method of displaying a custom post type featured post/page in WordPress?

Tags: wordpress

When working with custom post types in WordPress, what's the best method of displaying a featured post/page (as defined by a custom field) on the home page as well as other content?

Comment: Ah! Think I may of answered this myself. When querying custom post types, you need to specify the type, for example:

<code>$featured = new WP_Query();
$featured -> query('post_type=listings');</code>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let me add this in for reference

```
   http://codex.wordpress.org/Post_Types
```

to learn more about Custom Post types, check this slide

```
http://www.slideshare.net/williamsba/custom-post-types-and-taxonomies-in-wordpress
```